# Multiple argument with std::forward in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, forward

I have a struct which has 5 member, I initialize all argument with `std::forward` :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
struct OutputFilesName {
  template<typename T>
  OutputFilesName(
    T&& result_subdir_name,
    T&& result_TSIM_minus, 
    T&& result_TSIM_plus,
    T&& result_minus_total_dat, 
    T&& result_plus_total_dat,
    T&& result_hdl 
    ) : 
      subdir_name( std::forward<T>(result_subdir_name) ),
      TSIM_minus( std::forward<T>(result_TSIM_minus) ),
      TSIM_plus( std::forward<T>(result_TSIM_plus) ),
      minus_total_dat( std::forward<T>(result_minus_total_dat) ),
      plus_total_dat( std::forward<T>(result_plus_total_dat) ),
      hdl( std::forward<T>(result_hdl) ) {     
  }

  const std::string subdir_name;
  const std::string TSIM_minus;
  const std::string TSIM_plus;
  const std::string minus_total_dat;
  const std::string plus_total_dat;
  const std::string hdl;

  OutputFilesName() = delete;
};
```

I invoke that struct in main program:

```cpp
int main(){    
  OutputFilesName ofn(
    "a",
    "bb",
    "ccc",
    "dddd",
    "eeeee",
    "ffffff"
  );
}
```

The compiler throws an error, it seems that the argument cannot be parsed correctly:

```
./test_genHoughMap.cc:37:19: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'OutputFilesName'
  OutputFilesName ofn(
                  ^
./test_genHoughMap.cc:10:3: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T'
      ('char const (&)[2]' vs. 'char const (&)[3]')
  OutputFilesName(
  ^
./test_genHoughMap.cc:8:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires
      1 argument, but 6 were provided
struct OutputFilesName {
       ^
./test_genHoughMap.cc:8:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires
      1 argument, but 6 were provided
./test_genHoughMap.cc:33:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 6 were
      provided
  OutputFilesName() = delete;
  ^
1 error generated.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Your use of `OutputFilesName ofn` can only mean C++17, but you tagged C++11. Which is it?

Comment: Oh! my bad. Thanks your information.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica What is C++17-specific ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - The declaration in main. Looks like an attempt at CTAD.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The class itself is not a template, it holds `std::string`s.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - Could have swron when I first looked at it that the `template` introducer was on the class. Oh well

Comment: If only one argument into `std::forward`, that's OK. https://godbolt.org/z/hLYrfN

Comment: But if 2 argument is not:https://godbolt.org/z/pdj9q_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your constructor uses common type `T` for all arguments.
Now for first argument `char[2]` is deduced for second `char[3]` what is in conflict. If you pass all stings with same length [it compiles](https://www.godbolt.org/z/aNaBRK).

So for each argument you need different template parameter ([demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/sZqDNs)).

Anyway consider drooping use of explicit constructor and just use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) ([demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/aNaBRK)). Sadly this doesn't work in cases like `emplace_back`.

Comment: I need to add `explict` into construcor. Because this constructor cannot accept type `char[]`, despite it's satisfy safely upward cast (`char[]` -> `string`). That's right?

Comment: You can initialize aggregates with `()` syntax in C++20, so it will work with `emplace_back`.

Comment: @curlywei explicit has nothing to your problem. It only has impact if you have to write `OutputFilesName` in every place where it is constructed (so before C++11 your it will have no effect).

Answer (score 1):

Refer to *Marek R*'s answer,

I also provide a other solution,

which can allow type of input argument is `char[]` in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct OutputFilesName {
  template<typename T1,typename T2,typename T3,typename T4,typename T5,typename T6>
  OutputFilesName(
    T1&& result_subdir_name,
    T2&& result_TSIM_minus, 
    T3&& result_TSIM_plus,
    T4&& result_minus_total_dat, 
    T5&& result_plus_total_dat,
    T6&& result_hdl 
    ) : 
      subdir_name( std::forward<T1>(result_subdir_name) ),
      TSIM_minus( std::forward<T2>(result_TSIM_minus) ),
      TSIM_plus( std::forward<T3>(result_TSIM_plus) ),
      minus_total_dat( std::forward<T4>(result_minus_total_dat) ),
      plus_total_dat( std::forward<T5>(result_plus_total_dat) ),
      hdl( std::forward<T6>(result_hdl) ) {     
  }

  const std::string subdir_name;
  const std::string TSIM_minus;
  const std::string TSIM_plus;
  const std::string minus_total_dat;
  const std::string plus_total_dat;
  const std::string hdl;

  OutputFilesName() = delete;
};

int main(){    
  OutputFilesName ofn(
    "a",
    "bb",
    "ccc",
    "dddd",
    "eeeee",
    "ffffff"
  );
}
```

I change `<typename T>` to

`template<typename T1,typename T2,typename T3,typename T4,typename T5,typename T6>`

Each template type is inferred to its type independently.